# Trying to extrude and bevel a symbol on a curved path

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have been following a tutorial on how to make a curved, 3D film strip but I cannot get the strip to become 3D and extrude and bevel on a curved path. I create a curved line using the pen tool then click Effect-->3D-->Extrude and Bevel. I fix my settings, Map Art to the symbol I created, then click No Shading, and then OK. All I get is a curved line with a bunch of dashes as shown. Anyone know what's going on?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are mapping the art to one side or back side instead of front of the mesh.

You must play with the angle.

Map Art to the lighter mesh. That is the front view.

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: I keep rotating it around but I still get those dashed lines in the preview. What do you mean by Map Art to the lighter mesh?

Comment: I added another screenshot above to show my preview

Comment: Look at my Map Art panel. In surface, my front mesh is 5 of 7. If I put in anther one like 1 of 7, it maps my symbol to the backside of surface, showing just a dash. Click the triangles to view a lighter surface, not the greyed ones.